# Product Loop Size in Woocommerce 'archive-product.php' Issues

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, archive

I modified my Wordpress search result page by replacing the 'wp-search.php' with 'archive-product.php' (from Woocommerce) contents to make it relevant for e-commerce purpose.

It successfully changed the way I want it to be.

However, when the search results appear, the first product always comes bigger than the others. As shown here:

[image: screenshot]

link:
http://cardstory.co/?s=rounders

It seems that the first image loop comes in different layout size. But I don't know how to change it just like the others.

Please help. Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: If you could include some actual code in your question, it'll help people answer.

Comment: Are you sure the original pictures are even the same size? I'm seeing the first one is 514x600 and the second is 570x600. Presumably your shop thumbnail has a 600px height limit and is being cropped accordingly.